# Openstack error status on manila service

Tags: openstack

I took kolla-ansible tool to deploy pike openstack platform and enable manila service, and created the manila type and network with manila permission.  Finally I got manila service error status.  It is confirmed that provided manila service instance creating, but confused why do not start up volume in instance, I have check manila_share log , I have found the error issue, but I do not konw how to fix it.

I refer the https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-manila-dhss-true-option2.html to build manila service.

LOG:

```
2018-08-03 05:20:41.906 25 WARNING manila.share.drivers.service_instance [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] No key path is available. May be non-existent key path is provided. Check path_to_private_key (current value None) and path_to_public_key (current value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) in manila configuration file.: ShareServerNotFoundByFilters: Share server could not be found by filters: share_network_id is "052e2687-3f4a-4332-838c-c484fd8359ca", host is "openstack2@generic" and status in "creating" or "active".

2018-08-03 05:20:45.308 25 WARNING manila.network.linux.interface [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] Device tap656ec089-aa already exists.: NetworkException: Bad router request: Router already has a port on subnet 8a6e6f64-01b6-4d72-bbda-27efb87a2aff.
Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-b3f83ab5-a492-4b5c-a6a9-eb78688eb561']

2018-08-03 05:21:05.542 25 INFO manila.share.manager [req-972a6f11-6c92-4d2e-86d2-8cf1e9f04abb - - - - -] Updating share status

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] DBAPIError exception wrapped from (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO share_server_backend_details (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, deleted, `key`, value, share_server_id) VALUES (%(created_at)s, %(updated_at)s, %(deleted_at)s, %(deleted)s, %(key)s, %(value)s, %(share_server_id)s)'] [parameters: {'deleted': 'False', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 3, 9, 21, 7, 754910), 'updated_at': None, 'value': None, 'share_server_id': 'a61c26b8-ca35-4bd9-9d63-ca0273dbbc42', 'key': 'subnet_id', 'deleted_at': None}]: IntegrityError: (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null")

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     context)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     result = self._query(query)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     conn.query(q)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     result.read()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     packet.check_error()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     raise errorclass(errno, errval)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters IntegrityError: (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null")

2018-08-03 05:21:07.755 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters 

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] DBAPIError exception wrapped from (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO share_server_backend_details (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, deleted, `key`, value, share_server_id) VALUES (%(created_at)s, %(updated_at)s, %(deleted_at)s, %(deleted)s, %(key)s, %(value)s, %(share_server_id)s)'] [parameters: {'deleted': 'False', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 3, 9, 21, 7, 790935), 'updated_at': None, 'value': None, 'share_server_id': 'a61c26b8-ca35-4bd9-9d63-ca0273dbbc42', 'key': 'router_id', 'deleted_at': None}]: IntegrityError: (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null")
2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     context)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     result = self._query(query)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     conn.query(q)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     result.read()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     packet.check_error()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters     raise errorclass(errno, errval)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters IntegrityError: (1048, u"Column 'value' cannot be null")

2018-08-03 05:21:07.791 25 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.exc_filters 

2018-08-03 05:21:07.898 25 ERROR manila.share.manager [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] Creation of share instance 510c24f1-3bc5-4578-9c9f-49618a0de040 failed: failed to get share server.: NetworkException: Unable to find 'security_group' in request body
Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-55c16687-6cb5-4f2b-875a-77e3c5a58ff2']

2018-08-03 05:21:07.920 25 INFO manila.message.api [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] Creating message record for request_id = req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server [req-9958fce2-e2f6-41b0-9df0-f96a7beb9f4d 98b7a4537bf542e6a1d5447493ca9a06 5c725221beca48c88e77c956c0139ce6 - - -] Exception during message handling: NetworkException: Unable to find 'security_group' in request body
Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-55c16687-6cb5-4f2b-875a-77e3c5a58ff2']

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 160, in _process_incoming

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 213, in dispatch

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 183, in _do_dispatch

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 186, in wrapped

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/utils.py", line 560, in wrapper

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 1635, in create_share_instance

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     detail=message_field.Detail.NO_SHARE_SERVER)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 1617, in create_share_instance

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     share_group=share_group_ref,

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 537, in _provide_share_server_for_share

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return _wrapped_provide_share_server_for_share()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py", line 271, in inner

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return f(*args, **kwargs)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 533, in _wrapped_provide_share_server_for_share

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     metadata=metadata))

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 549, in _create_share_server_in_backend

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     metadata=metadata)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 3427, in _setup_server
2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.driver.deallocate_network(context, share_server['id'])

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/manager.py", line 3378, in _setup_server

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     network_info, metadata=metadata)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/driver.py", line 893, in setup_server

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._setup_server(*args, **kwargs)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/drivers/generic.py", line 878, in _setup_server

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.admin_context, network_info)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/drivers/service_instance.py", line 407, in set_up_service_instance

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     context, instance_name, network_info)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/drivers/service_instance.py", line 545, in _create_service_instance

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     security_group = self._get_or_create_security_group(context)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py", line 271, in inner

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return f(*args, **kwargs)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/share/drivers/service_instance.py", line 336, in _get_or_create_security_group

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     name, description)['security_group']

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/manila/network/neutron/api.py", line 388, in security_group_create

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     code=e.status_code, message=e.message)

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server NetworkException: Unable to find 'security_group' in request body

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-55c16687-6cb5-4f2b-875a-77e3c5a58ff2']

2018-08-03 05:21:07.929 25 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server 

2018-08-03 05:22:05.553 25 INFO manila.share.manager [req-972a6f11-6c92-4d2e-86d2-8cf1e9f04abb - - - - -] Updating share status

2018-08-03 05:23:05.529 25 INFO manila.share.manager [req-972a6f11-6c92-4d2e-86d2-8cf1e9f04abb - - - - -] Updating share status
```